# PHP how to use html tags/entities in variable?

Tags: php, html, tags

I have content that  I want to display in a textarea. And on a another page in a div. 
The content I got from inside my  database. And was inserted in the database with CKeditor.
Sound easy, right?

The problem is that when I use echo or print I am getting `<b>Some content</b>` instead of **Some content**.

Believe it or not I spend 6 hours already trying to solve this problem. What is normal amount for me to spend on a problem. Only normally I am at least one step closer solving the problem. But now I am still as clueless as I started.

And yes I am using:  `<meta charset="utf-8">`

My code(Just a basic echo, since I don`t know what to do)

```
<textarea ><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
```

Current output:

```
<li><s><em><strong><span class="marker">Dit is gewijzigd?</span></strong>
```

But I would like this:

**Dit is gewijzigd?**

Comment: Whatever is wrong, lies inside code or configuration you didn't shared yet.

Comment: Your echo is using `htmlspecialchars()` see this  http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp you will get the idea  , now think how you can do this or ask again.

Comment: You can't have html formating in textarea. This is the problem ?

Comment: Please post the format of the code for the `textarea` that is stored in the database.

Comment: @Jamesking56 Here: &lt;blockquote&gt;
&lt;ol&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Dit is bold&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;&lt;em&gt;Dit is schuin&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;&lt;s&gt;Dit is sssss&lt;/s&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;marker&quot;&gt;Ik ben een marker&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;
 &lt;h1&gt;&lt;s&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;marker&quot;&gt;$CHINCHINGHINC&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/s&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
 &lt;/li&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;&lt;s&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;marker&quot;&gt;  And a bit more.

Comment: @Alan Machado I doubt it. Why?  Its a simple Query.  Nothing special, except that I have nothing on the page.

Comment: Because of your comments on the answers, saying things didn't work out. People covered htmlspecialchars, tag strip, decoding html entities and you said it didn't work. I was betting on browser or environment configs.

Comment: I think  @Jamesking56 was right. You cannot do it in a textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try it like this to make the content editable

```
<div contenteditable><?php echo $content; ?></div>
```

EDIT :

try this

```
<div><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($content); ?></div>
```

Comment: No, I want to display the content. And don`t allow anyone to edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use strip_tags() function :

```
<textarea ><?php echo strip_tags($content); ?></textarea>
```

Docs here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using js as -- You need two times decoding since as you shown your raw data in db ..

```
<textarea id='t'></textarea>
<script>
function getHTML(code)
{
var para = document.createElement("DIV");
para.innerHTML=code;
//return $(para).text(); 
 return para.innerText; 
}
document.getElementById('t').innerHTML=getHTML('<?php echo $content; ?>');
</script>
```

**PURE PHP**

```
<textarea id='t'><?php echo html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($content));?></textarea>
```

Comment: I tried. Maybe I am doing something wrong. But it did not seems to work for me.

Comment: are you applying any editor further on this textarea??

Comment: No, I don`t have any editor in the page. I also have no other JS on the page.

Comment: Already, thank I copy and past it. Is seems to be working. I do prefer the other solution. Without JS. Although I should really use JS, I am almost never do.

Comment: now it will do as per your need , check it again  @dutchrocks

Answer (score 0):

you can do couple of things to figure out

1) use the html_entity_decode function which will decode the html entity which is coming from database and return the html output

2) if the above solution doesn't work then use the first try to echo with html_entity_decode to check that does it work properly or not if it does then there is something we need to do with editor as so that editor will know that it is getting the raw html data not just plain text. i also used the FCKeditor where i have simply put the text and its working fine.

Comment: 1 did not work. 2 I don`t fully understand.  If I put the content in the CKeditor I will work. However I don`t want that.

Comment: any specific reason for not putting the raw html content inside editor ??